# MVC: No parameterless constructor for this object

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know I can correct the problem by simply adding a parameterless constructor to the model, but I would like to understand why.

The standard MVC template in VS2013 has an `error` view in the Shared folder.  It takes a `HandleErrorInfo` class as its model.  This view is called directly from various places and there is no matching `Error` action defined.

I added an Error action intending to add logging:

```
public ActionResult Error(HandleErrorInfo model)
{
    //TODO! Log error
    return View(model);
}
```

This resulted in the `No parameterless constructor defined for this object` exception when I called:

```
return RedirectToAction("error", model);
```

The above pattern is everywhere in the project, and all the models I see also do not have a parameterless constructor.  Why is it happening in this Error action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an `ActionResult` method is called, the `DefaultModelBinder` first initializes an instance of the model. Internally it uses `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()` static method. From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hcyx2kd(v=vs.110).aspx), this will throw a `MissingMethodException` if

> The type that is specified for T does not have a parameterless constructor.

`HandleErrorInfo` does not have a parameterless constructor, hence the exception

Comment: Does C# assume there is a parameterless constructor if there are no constructors defined for the class?  All the models in AccountViewModles have no parameterless constructors but they work fine.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, Absence of a constructor means in effect it has a parameterless constructor.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your doing with this, but you might want to consider using Elmah or one of the other similar libraries for error logging ([refer this article](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/DotNetSlackersArticle))